# Passing django user as redirect request header

Tags: django, redirect, request, http-headers

I have a (non-django) application **A** that requires a username to login. This app allows for pre authorization, which I want to provide from my django application **B**. However app **A** requires that the username is set as a *remote_user* request header. What I tried to do is create a view in django app **B** that redirects to app **A** passing a *remote_user* header.

**urls.py**

```py
url(r'^{0}to_app_a$'.format(DJANGO_BASE), 'app.views.to_app_a')
```

**views.py**

```py
def to_app_a(request):
  response = redirect('http://app_a')
  response['remote_user] = request.user

  return response
```

The problem with that is that the header is lost on redirect and never reaches the request to `http://app_a` external app. It has been suggested to use cookies instead, but unfortunately app **A** won't accept anything else than a *remote_user* request header.

Has anyone come up with a solution to such issue?

Thank you

Comment: There's no way to tell the user-agent what headers to use when redirecting. The only alternative is to implement your own redirection functionality in Javascript and skip HTTP redirects entirely.

Comment: I see... Javascript is an option but on a second thought, is this approach vulnerable to spoofing?

Comment: If you're using the header for authentication (as opposed to pre-filling a username field), and the value is guessable (such as a username), then definitely! If the value is not guessable, then you're basically re-creating token authentication.